# How to get value from three tables?

Tags: mysql, database

I have three tables like these:

```
-drivingtime
  +id
  +starttime
  +stoptime
-fuel
  +id
  +timestamp
  +fuellevel
-addingfuel
  +id
  +timestamp
  +fueladding
```

and I expected to show starttime,stoptime,fuellevel (at starttime),fuellevel (at stoptime),fueladding on the same screen. So what exactly I have to do? I searched google for solution but the other problems were quite different.

I tried:

```
SELECT startTime and stopTime 
from tblDrivingTime d 
left join tblFuel f on d.startTime = f.timestamp 
left join tblFuel f on d.stopTime = f.timestamp 
left join tblDoXang x on d.startTime < x.timestamp < d.stopTime
```

Comment: Please add your attempt to achieve your results

Comment: do you mean that there is some ways to do so?

Comment: did u hear about `JOIN` in `sql`?

Comment: I'm very new in sql and haven't done with multiple tables before

Comment: Use `JOIN` for this. If required you can join the same table many times (two joins for `fuel`). More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: I wrote the query like that:` SELECT startTime and stopTime from tblDrivingTime d
left join tblFuel f
on d.startTime = f.timestamp
left join tblFuel f
on d.stopTime = f.timestamp
left join tblDoXang x
on d.startTime < x.timestamp < d.stopTime` but it was'nt run correctly

Comment: Is there an entry in table `fuel` for every `starttime` and `stoptime` of table `drivingtime`? Is there only one `addingfuel` action during a driving session? If not, how do you want to get this info (aggregate fuel for the entire session, number of adding events,...)?

Comment: @JoëlSalamin I want to see number of adding events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that returns the result you are looking for:

```
SELECT DT.starttime
    ,DT.stoptime
    ,FB.fuellevel AS `startfuellevel`
    ,FE.fuellevel AS `stopfuellevel`
    ,(SELECT COUNT(AF.id)
     FROM addingfuel AF
     WHERE AF.timestamp BETWEEN DT.starttime AND DT.stoptime) AS `nbaddingevents
FROM drivingtime DT
INNER JOIN fuel FB ON FB.timestamp = DT.starttime
INNER JOIN fuel FE ON FE.timestamp = DT.stoptime
```

Hope this will help you.